# Pulling out balls from boxes, when their quantity is unknown

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

This is a problem that I saw in a previous exam in my university:

There are 3 types of balls in a box: white, blue and red (their quantity is unknown).  We pull out a ball from a box randomly, and if it is not red- we return it to the box. We keep doing it until we get a red ball, and then we stop pulling out balls. Let $X$ be the number of blue balls pulled out, $Y$ the number of white balls pulled out and $L$ the number of total balls that were pulled out. Find the distribution of $X|L=k$ ,$Y|L=k$ ,$L$.

My attempt: it’s easy to tell that $(X|L=k), (Y|L=k)$~$B(k-1,p_1)$  and $L$~$G(p_2)$. Now we need to find $p_1$ and $p_2$.
$p_1$ is the probability to pull out blue ball (white ball for  $(Y|L=k)$, It’s symmetric) and $p_2$ is the probability to pull out red ball. The problem is that the quantity of the balls is unknown, and therefore I don’t know how to calculate $p_1,p_2$. I saw in the solution of that exam that $p_1=0.5 , p_2=1/3$ and I don’t understand why. If for example we have one blue ball, 10 white balls and 10 red balls in the box- then $p_1,p_2$ are not correct.

Can you explain why  $p_1=0.5 , p_2=1/3$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My attempt: it’s easy to tell that $(X|L=k),(Y|L=k)\sim B(k−1,p_1)$ and 
>   $L\sim G(p_2)$.

To be sure, $(X\mid L{=}k)\sim\mathcal {Bin}(k-1,p_1)~,~ (Y\mid L{=}k)\sim\mathcal{Bin}(k-1,1-p_1)~,~ L\sim\mathcal{Geo}_1(p_2)$

Where if the number of red, blue, and white balls are $r,b,w$ we have $p_1=\frac{b}{b+w}, p_2=\frac r{r+w+b}$

Then $p_1=1/2, p_2=1/3$ happens when we have $r=b=w$; that is the same amount for each colour of ball.

Either there is some information missing from the problem, or you are expected to just *assume* that there are an equal quantity of balls of each type in the box as a **Bayesian Prior**.

Comment: why p1=b/(b+w) ? isn't it suppose to be b/(b+w+r)?

Comment: @john $X\mid L{=}k$ is the count of black balls among the $k-1$ balls that are not the first red ball (when given that happens on draw $k$).  $~p_1$ is the conditional probability of selecting a black ball when given that it is not red.